# How can I get the ttyACM0 device from host to lxc container

Tags: ubuntu, lxc, z-wave

I'm trying to get the /dev/ttyACM0 device on the host to be used in an LXC container.  The device is an Aeotec Z-Wave Plus USB controller.

I'm Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on the host and the same in the container, with LXC version 3.0.1.

So far, I've only found examples of passing usb drives through.  I tried those examples modified for the specific device, but to no avail.  Since I'm running lxc 2, there is no config file similar to lxc 1, that I have been able to find.  I did try to create a config file, but it wasn't recognized.

```
lxc config device add homeassistant sigma usb vendorid=0658 productid=0200
```

Any suggestions on where to look?

Thank You for your time,

Harlan...

P.S.  I realized after submitting this should be under the Stack Unix/Linux domain, but I don't know how to move it there.